# How do I remove Supervised mode on the iPad so I can attach it to another computer?

Tags: ipad, apple-configurator, mobile-device-management

I can't really figure out a way to connect to another machine once the device is in Supervised mode. Supervision Mode seems to embed itself into the operating system.

I am getting this error every time I connect to iTunes on a different machine (Windows 7 32-bit, or Mac OS X 10.10.2):

[image]

I used Apple Configurator to lock down the device and turned on "Supervision" in Apple Configurator:

[image]

Even if I remove the profile (Settings > General > Profile), I still get the supervision error.

My intent was to import pictures on a different machine, but the iPad will not show up as a device in iTunes, Windows Explorer, nor Mac Finder.

I should add that I assigned the iPad Mini 2 to myself using the "Assign" feature, if that makes a difference.

Comment: For what particular reason are you putting this iPad in Supervised mode?

Comment: We want a specific configuration to be deployed. When we perform quarterly maintenance, any deviation from the approved configuration will be reset. The device has one custom application that is used to submit data to an internal server. No data on the iPad needs to be saved. You do bring up a good point though about not using Supervision Mode and perhaps you Assign instead to save user data during check-in and check-out.